# Почему в "постоянный" две Н?

Tags: прилагательные, морфология

Почему прилагательное *постоя**нн**ый* пишется с двумя Н? Ведь суффиксы *ан*/*ян* имеют одну Н (кроме слов *оловянный*, *деревянный* и т.д.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, Вам отвечали уже на подобный вопрос. Одна Н пишется в суффиксах именных прилагательных. Слово же "постоянный" происходит от устаревшего "постояти" (продолжаться), т.е. это отглагольное прилагательное с суффиксом НН, а не -ЯН